# Grouping different rows into single row of sql server

Tags: sql, t-sql

Link of resultset query
http://screencast.com/t/8Su2cACxBtq

I want to show data without NULL values into single row,

```
with cte as (
    Select QuestionID,SubmitDate,
    Case when  QuestionID=860 and Answers='Yes' then   Answers    End as 'Ans1A',
    case when  QuestionID=861 then Answers else NULL End as 'Answer2A',
    case when  QuestionID=862 then Answers  ELSE NULL End as 'Answer3A',
    case when  QuestionID=863 then Answers  Else NULL End as 'Answer4A',
    Case when  QuestionID=864 and Answers='Yes' then   Answers    End as 'Ans2B',
    case when  QuestionID=865 then Answers else NULL End as 'Answer2B',
    case when  QuestionID=866 then Answers  ELSE NULL End as 'Answer3B',
    case when  QuestionID=867 then Answers  Else NULL End as 'Answer4B'
     From Question_Users Where SurveyId=28 and QuestionID in (860,861,862,863,864,865,866,867) and SubmitDate is not null
     )
select * 
from cte
```

Sample data for above sql query

```
QID + Ans1A + Ans2A+ Ans3A,Ans4A+ Ans1B+Ans2B+Ans3B+Ans4B   
860   + Yes +  Null + Null +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
861   + Null + abc + Null +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
862   + Null + Null + abc +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
863   + Null + Null + Null +   abc+   Null  + Null + Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   abc+ Null + Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + abc+ Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + Null + abc+ Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + Null + Null + abc
860   + Yes +  Null + Null +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
861   + Null + abc + Null +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
862   + Null + Null + abc +   Null +   Null  + Null + Null +  Null
863   + Null + Null + Null +   abc+   Null  + Null + Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   abc+ Null + Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + abc+ Null + Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + Null + abc+ Null
864   + Null + Null + Null +   Null  +   Null  + Null + Null + abc
```

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  Any query you have tried is also useful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can just use aggregation:

```
Select submitdate,
       max(Case when  QuestionID=860 and Answers='Yes' then Answers End) as Ans1A,
       max(case when  QuestionID=861 then Answers End) as Answer2A,
       max(case when  QuestionID=862 then Answers End) as Answer3A,
       max(case when  QuestionID=863 then Answers End) as Answer4A,
       max(Case when  QuestionID=864 and Answers='Yes' then Answers end) as Ans2B,
       max(case when  QuestionID=865 then Answers end) as Answer2B,
       max(case when  QuestionID=866 then Answers end) as Answer3B,
       max(case when  QuestionID=867 then Answers end) as Answer4B
From Question_Users
Where SurveyId = 28 and
      QuestionID in (860, 861, 862, 863, 864, 865, 866, 867) and
      SubmitDate is not null
Group by submitdate;
```

Comment: I also used pivot table but it return only one row, i try above query it return one row.

Comment: Your sample data suggests that you only want one row.  Perhaps you want to aggregate by `.submitdate`.